# I installed the keycloak and configured the LDAP, but in the user page, it doesn't list the users of the LDAP. Can anyone solve this?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I installed the keycloak version of 22.0.1 and configured the LDAP users. When I sync all users, it shows 0 users imported and 22 users added. On the Users page, it doesn't show the users of LDAP. I checked the configuration of LDAP, and all is correct, but in key cloack, it doesn't show the LDAP users. The Java version is 11. This is all I do on Windows 10.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHQNb.png)

I have tried to sync the LDAP users in Keycloak; the test connection and authentication are successful, but the users don't list in the Keycloak users page, and I checked the object class and attributes, which are all correct in the LDAP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching with an asterisk “*”.